# Too many bits from 24bit ADC?

Tags: serial-port, bit, adc

I'm using an ADuC834 from Analog Devices to measure some voltages. I'm storing the results in a table containing 34 LONG numbers. The storing procedure is shown below (BASCOM):

```
  Adcout = 0

  Adcout = Adcout Or Adc0h

  Shift Adcout , Left , 8

  Adcout = Adcout Or Adc0m

  Shift Adcout , Left , 8

  Adcout = Adcout Or Adc0l

  Result(count) = Adcout
```

After completing all conversions they're being sent via RS232 port.

```
  Printhex Result(count)
```

Instead of receiving 24 bits I get 25 bits.

The result have the form of `0x01HHMMLL` whereas they should look like `0x00HHMMLL`.

Where can this additional bit come from? Should I treat it as part of the conversion result?

Thank you for your help.
Łukasz

Comment: Are Adc0h, Adc0m and Adc0l 8 bit values? If not you should mask them to 8 bit (by doing Adcout = Adcout or (Adc0x and 0xff))

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes Adc0h, Adc0m and Adc0l are declared as Bytes.

Comment: Then I can only guess, that the error is in the RS232 transfer, as the computation itself can only be <= 24 bits. You can output Adcout before transfering?